# Moving multiple extension file name in another directory

Tags: bash, scripts, mv

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to find and move files

SOURCE=/DRIVE2/folder/
DESTDIR=/DRIVE/new3/

MOVEFILES=(mpg avi m4v mp4 3gp mpeg MOV) 
# this line above is not working, its only reading the first extension

find $SOURCE -type f -name *.$MOVEFILES -print | xargs -i mv -v "{}" $DESTDIR
```

Can you guys help me with my bash script? The `$MOVEFILES` part of my script is not working. It's only reading the first extension I put there which is `mpg`. The rest is being ignored. What is the proper way to write that line?

Also is it possible to include the directory its from lets say
`/DRIVE2/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/file.ext` move to `/DRIVE/folder3/folder4/file.ext`

Comment: How did you decide which part of `folder1/folder2/...` to retain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `find` with `-regex`

```
MOVEFILES=".*\.\(mpg\|avi\|m4v\)"
find "$SOURCE" -type f -regex "$MOVEFILES" -exec mv {} "$DESTDIR" \;
```

You could also use `-iregex` instead of `-regex` for case-insensitve matches like `AvI` and so on.

All the `\` looks ugly, I know. `-regextype posix-extended`, as used in [@Murus answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/697719/367165), looks better.

Comment: Yes, sure, but @mure has the better explanation. You should accept the other answer. ;)

Comment: Cool, didn't know about find's exec flag.

Answer (score 6):

You should probably use `-regex` instead of `-name` - with `-name`, each extension will need a seperate `-name` test:

```
find .. -name '*.mp4' -name '*.avi' ...
```

Instead:

```
find -regextype posix-extended ... -regex '.*\.(mp4|avi|...)' ...
```

Given your array, do (ditching the unnecessary `xargs`):

```
find "$SOURCE" -regextype posix-extended  -type f -regex ".*\.($(IFS="|"; echo "${MOVEFILES[*]}"))" -exec mv -t "$DESTDIR" {} +
```

`IFS="|"; echo "${MOVEFILES[*]}"` is a way to print every element in the `MOVEFILES` array separated by `|`.

`$MOVEFILES` by itself is just the first element in the `MOVEFILES` array.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by using only shell (`bash`):

```
shopt -s extglob globstar nullglob 
mv -t /destination **/*(*.mpg|*.m4v|*.mpeg|*.mp4|*.avi|*.3gp|*.MOV)
```

- At first we need to set a few shell options
- `extglob` will enable us to do extended pattern matching for filenames
- `globstar`, after enabling this, by using `**` we can traverse through subdirectories to search for the files
- `nullglob` will result in a null string if no file name is matched by our given patterns rather than the patterns themselves
- Now, `*(*.foo|*.bar)` is a `extglob` pattern which will match zero or more occurrences of either `*.foo` or `*.bar`
- So combinedly, `**/*(*.mpg|*.m4v|*.mpeg|*.mp4|*.avi|*.3gp|*.MOV)` will get us the files to be moved
- `mv -t /destination **/*(*.mpg|*.m4v|*.mpeg|*.mp4|*.avi|*.3gp|*.MOV)` will move the files to the `/destination`.

**Example:**

```
$ tree 
.
├── dest
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   ├── baz.md
│   │   ├── egg.3gp
│   │   └── egg.mp4
│   ├── baz.txt
│   ├── spam.avi
│   └── spam.mp3
├── spamegg.MOV
└── spamegg.txt


$ shopt -s extglob globstar nullglob 

$ mv -t dest/ **/*(*.mp3|*.mp4|*.avi|*.3gp|*.MOV)

$ tree 
.
├── dest
│   ├── egg.3gp
│   ├── egg.mp4
│   ├── spam.avi
│   ├── spamegg.MOV
│   └── spam.mp3
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── baz.md
│   └── baz.txt
└── spamegg.txt
```

Comment: Side note (not for you heemayl, for other people reading this): `extglob` is always disabled when Bash is run non-interactively (script, `bash -c` etc) but it's always enabled when Bash is run interactively, so you won't need to turn `extglob` on unless you're running this from a script (or from `bash -c`).

Answer (score 2):

`find` command allows setting multiple conditions with `-o` flag and you don't really need `xargs`, you can use `-exec`. Personally, I'd change your script to

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to find and move files

SOURCE=/DRIVE2/folder/
DESTDIR=/DRIVE/new3/


find "$SOURCE" -type f \( -name -o "*.mpg" -o -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.m4v" -o -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.3gp"  -o -name "*.mpeg" -o -name "*.MOV" \) -exec mv -t "$DESTDIR" {} +
```

Another approach would be with a for loop , where we work on each extension individually

```
for EXT in ${MOVEFILES[@]}; do find "$SOURCE" -type f -name "*.$EXT" -exec mv -t "$DESTDIR" {} +   ; done
```

Comment: `-t $DESTDIR` is great!